# PowerShell and Onenote

Tags: powershell, onenote

I would like to read and write on OneNote pages using PowerShell scripts. I have been trying different scripts I found, but none of them even run on my machine. I am wondering if I have to enable something, or get some kind of library.

When trying to run some scripts I found, I get this error:

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.InterOp.OneNote.HierarchyScope].
At line:3 char:27
+ ... erarchy("", [Microsoft.Office.InterOp.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPage ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Offic....HierarchyScope:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Or is it even possible?

PS Version: 5.1.17134.407
OneNote 2013

Comment: Show us the code that is generating the error. Right now, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: You can try to add the assembly:

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote

Comment: I used # Examples
# get a table of all notebooks

$OneNote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
[xml]$Hierarchy = ""
$OneNote.GetHierarchy("", [Microsoft.Office.InterOp.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPages, [ref]$Hierarchy)

$Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook | Format-Table Name, path, isUnread, isCurrentlyViewed

Comment: Palansen: Adding the assembly made Postanote's script work! thanks

Comment: @VST, adding the namespace/assembly for any MSOffice COM interop is a requirement for any  MSOffice app and that was in the info in the links provided. It is a common use case. Think of the assemblies no different than you'd think of using download PowerShell modules, they have to be loaded before they can be used. Yet, it's good that Palansen pointed you there again.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Theo on this one.

How are you trying to run them, consolehost, ISE, VSCode, other editor?
Did you set your ExecutionPolicy so that you could run them at all.
Is OneNote on your machine and activated or are you trying to hit a remote box?

However, there is a provider you can use to assist you here...

[OneNotePowerShellProvider](https://github.com/sytone/OneNotePowerShellProvider)

```
# Example Scripts
Name                           
----                           
ConvertTo-Object.ps1           
Create-OneNoteDocumentation.ps1
Export-PsOn.ps1                
Get-OneNoteApplication.ps1     
Get-OneNoteDigest.ps1          
Get-OneNoteText.ps1            
Get-ProviderTests.ps1          
Import-FilesToOneNote.ps1      
Robocopy-Items.ps1             
Set-OneNoteDebug.ps1           
Start-Tests.ps1
```

… as well as this article...

[Read and Write Content from OneNote with PowerShell](http://thebackend.info/powershell/2017/12/onenote-read-and-write-content-with-powershell/)

```
# Examples
# get a table of all notebooks

$OneNote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
[xml]$Hierarchy = ""
$OneNote.GetHierarchy("", [Microsoft.Office.InterOp.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPages, [ref]$Hierarchy)

$Hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook | Format-Table Name, path, isUnread, isCurrentlyViewed
```

Comment: I am using ISE. I do not know about the execution policy, but I know my other scripts are running. OneNote and PS are running on my own machine. I am using PS because I can't run Python on that computer (it's a work computer)

Comment: Your solution, with Palansen's solution to add the assembly (Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote) seem to have made it work.. I work on it and come back if I need further guidance. thank you

Comment: You can see your EP setting by simply using the EP cmdlet. `Get-ExecutionPolicy`. There   are [`scopes` for them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1),  and you can have one set for your host, and one you set for your session, and they can be different. Regardless of the EP setting, if you have code in the ISE, just select it all and hit run and it will execute. EP only affects saved scripts, then when you try and run the. EP is not a security boundary.